# State change in Arduino Using Adafruit display

Tags: programming

```
if(menustate == 1310){menustate ++;Serial.println("Execution:");Serial.println(menustate);}        
             if(menustate == 1311){menustate ++;if (hr==0) menustate ++;else{aCount++;gpArray[aCount]=hr;}Serial.println("Execution GP:");Serial.println(menustate);}
             if(menustate == 1312){menustate ++;if (minu==0) menustate ++;else{aCount++;gpArray[aCount]=minu;}Serial.println("Execution GP:");Serial.println(menustate);}
             if(menustate == 1313){menustate ++;if (seco==0) menustate ++;else{aCount++;gpArray[aCount]=seco;}Serial.println("Execution GP:");Serial.println(menustate);}
             if(menustate == 1314){menustate ++;if (dates==0) menustate ++;else{aCount++;gpArray[aCount]=dates;}Serial.println("Execution GP:");Serial.println(menustate);}
             if(menustate == 1315){menustate ++;if (months==0) menustate ++;else{aCount++;gpArray[aCount]=years;}Serial.println("Execution GP:");Serial.println(menustate);}
             if(menustate == 1316){menustate ++;if (years==0) menustate ++;else{aCount++;gpArray[aCount]=years;}}
             if(menustate == 1320){menustate ++;}
```

I am trying to get different time inputs from users by using the menustate value , but here in this code the menustate starts from 1311 and without pressing anything the state goes directly to 1320 .and i cant get to the inbetween states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a switch statement ... than after the switch statement you get the in between states:

```
// conditional loop
{

    // prepare for switch (if something is needed)

    switch (menustate)
    {
        case 1310:
            menustate ++;
            Serial.println("Execution:");Serial.println(menustate);
            break;
        case 1311:
            menustate ++;
            if (hr==0) 
                 menustate ++;
            else
            { 
                aCount++;
                gpArray[aCount]=hr;
            }
            Serial.println("Execution GP:");Serial.println(menustate);
        break;

        case 1312:
            // ...

        default:
            // You can do here things with all other values
    }

    // Here you have the in between states available
}
```

You should put this switch statement in some conditional loop (like until an end state is reached.